# Custom handling for error 500 in Spring/Java

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I want to add the ability in my application which is using Spring framework that whenever an error 500 occurs in any place I handle it using filter or wrapper. Maybe it could send an email with a full stack trace of this exception, any ideas?

Comment: What about using `error-page`? (see there for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694136/error-controller-with-java-servlets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

take a look at the uncaughtExceptionHandler

[UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)

Comment: well this sample was very useful for me http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/javaxservleterrorrequesturi.htm\